# Last 6 months aggregation

Tags: oracle

I have the table containing data about calls, column CALLDATE contains the date and time of call.

I need the query which will return the number of calls per each month in last 6 months.

The result should look like:

```
PERIOD|CALLS
======|=====
201705|15235
201704|14965
201703|    0 <-- no data for this month
201702|12365
201701|13468
201612|14563
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -0), 'MON')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -2), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'MON')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -3), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -2), 'MON')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -4), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -3), 'MON')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -5), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -4), 'MON')
UNION
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM mytable
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -6), 'MON')
                    AND TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -5), 'MON')
```

Maybe there's easier solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your attempts explaining what's wrong with them. Also, posting a solution without knowing your table structure and input data may be difficult

Comment: Also, how do you compute the last 6 months? At 29/05, should the query include data from 29/12/2016 on? Or should it always get the whole december 2016? And what should it do, for example, on August 31?

Comment: From the result shown one can conclude that I need from 1. of month to the last day in month.

Comment: @Aleksej I can make a query with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE calldate BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON') AND TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MON')` for each month successively (in last six months) and union all them, but maybe there's better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
select TO_CHAR(CALLDATE,'yyyymm'),count(*)
from yourTable
--filter last n months (in this case 7)
where CALLDATE> SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' MONTH
--group by month
group by TO_CHAR(CALLDATE,'yyyymm');
```

If you need zeros for months without a call:

```
WITH MONTH_COUNTER AS (
  SELECT LEVEL-1 AS ID 
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
), all_month as ( 
  --last 6 months
  SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -ID),'yyyymm') m FROM MONTH_COUNTER
), all_count as (
  --previous query
  select TO_CHAR(CALLDATE,'yyyymm') m,count(*) c
  from yourTable
  where CALLDATE> SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' MONTH
  group by TO_CHAR(CALLDATE,'yyyymm')
)
--nvl = when count(*) is null then put 0
select all_month.m,nvl(all_count.c,0)
from all_month
left outer join all_count
on all_month.m = all_count.m;
```

Comment: Finally
`WITH periods AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-LEVEL),'YYYYMM') AS p FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVLEL<=6) SELECT TO_CHAR(calldate,'YYYYMM') period,COUNT(*) FROM mytable JOIN periods ON p=TO_CHAR(calldate,'YYYYMM') GROUP BY TO_CHAR(calldate,'YYYYMM') ORDER BY 1 DESC`

Answer (score 0):

One way could be creating a list of months, starting from sysdate and going 6 months back, and using your table in outer jon respect to this table.
For example:

```
/* sample data */
with yourTable(callDate) as (
    select date '2017-05-15' from dual union all
    select date '2017-05-15' from dual union all
    select date '2017-04-15' from dual union all
    select date '2017-03-15' from dual union all
    select date '2017-03-15' from dual union all
    select date '2017-02-15' from dual union all
    select date '2016-12-15' from dual
)     
/* the query */
select count(callDate), 
       to_char(monthStart, 'yyyymm')
from (
        select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Month'), -level +1) monthStart,
               last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Month'), -level +1)) monthEnd
        from dual
        connect by level <= 6
     ) months
     left join yourTable
       on calldate between monthStart and monthEnd
group by to_char(monthStart, 'yyyymm') 
order by to_char(monthStart, 'yyyymm')
```

Which gives:

```
COUNT(CALLDATE) TO_CHA
--------------- ------
              1 201612
              0 201701
              1 201702
              2 201703
              1 201704
              2 201705

6 rows selected.
```

This is mainly based on the construction of a set of relevant months with their start and end day:

```
SQL> select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Month'), -level +1) monthStart,
  2                     last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Month'), -level +1)) monthEnd
  3              from dual
  4              connect by level <= 6;

MONTHSTAR MONTHEND
--------- ---------
01-MAY-17 31-MAY-17
01-APR-17 30-APR-17
01-MAR-17 31-MAR-17
01-FEB-17 28-FEB-17
01-JAN-17 31-JAN-17
01-DEC-16 31-DEC-16

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Problem here is that GROUP BY query will not return row with COUNT zero for month if there was no calls (or data for that month are missing). I need 6 records regardless if there is or no call data.